# Why is this system of equations not working?

Tags: calculus

$y=x^2/2$, $y=ln(x)$..... $dy/dx=x, dy/dx=1/x$, so $x^2=1$ or $x=+or-1$. However, this solution doesn't work. Why not? Thanks! (and maybe the $-1$ somehow is a correct imaginary solution? I have no idea about this imaginary stuff, I'm just guessing here)

Comment: Assuming you're trying to find the coordinates of where the graphs of these functions intersect: You have made an inaccurate assumption, that if $y_1(x)=y_2(x)$ then $y_1'(x)=y_2'(x)$. Think about what the derivative means: derivative is just slope of the tangent. If the graphs of two functions meet at a point, they don't have to have the same derivative (try graphing $\frac{1}{2}x^2$ and $\log(x)$ on the same set of axes and you'll see what I mean.<br> This problem has no elementary closed form solution.

Comment: Oh ok I see. And is there a way to prove that this has no elementary solution, or just nobody has found it and it is assumed that it doesn't exist?

Comment: A solution would have $x^2/2=\ln x$; exponentiating we get $x=e^{x^2/2}$.  There's no "nice" form for a solution, although we can express it in terms of series, or other approximations.

Comment: Well yea I understand but is it possible to prove that there isn't any very clever trick which would allow you to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that in trying to find the derivatives of your two functions $y_1, y_2$ and setting the *derivatives equal* that you have ***incorrectly*** concluded that  $y_1 = y_2\iff \large \frac{dy_1}{dx} = \frac{dy_2}{dx}$.

What you are trying to solve is $$\ln x = \dfrac 12 x^2\iff 2\ln x = x^2$$ And what you *can do* is exponentiate each side of the equation giving you $$e^{x^2/2} = e^{\ln(x)} = x$$

Unfortunately, there is [no elementary closed form solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28x%29%20=%20%28x%5E2%29/2) to this equation.

Comment: Nice explanation! =1